# Radeon R7 260X - No 3D Acceleration in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: radeon

Radeon R7 260X graphics card, used to work fine in 17.10. After the upgrade to 18.04 it's only doing software rendering.

```
$ lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Bonaire XTX [Radeon R7 260X/360] [1002:6658]
```

Xorg.log indicates that Direct rendering is disabled, but doesn't show a reason why. No /etc/X11/xorg.conf is used here, creating one and manually enabling DRI didn't change anything either.

/dev/dri/ is present and I am in the group `video`:

```
$ ls -l /dev/dri/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root        80 Apr 18 16:45 by-path
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 226,   0 Apr 18 16:45 card0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 226, 128 Apr 18 16:45 renderD128
```

Relevant part of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[  1095.745] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[  1095.745] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[  1095.745] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[  1095.745] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[  1095.745] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[  1095.745] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[  1095.749] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1095.749]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[  1095.749]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  1095.749] (II) glamor: OpenGL accelerated X.org driver based.
[  1095.804] (EE) RADEON(0): eglGetDisplay() failed
[  1095.805] (EE) RADEON(0): glamor detected, failed to initialize EGL.
...
[  1096.275] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[  1096.276] (II) RADEON(0): Front buffer size: 46980K
[  1096.276] (II) RADEON(0): VRAM usage limit set to 157831K
[  1096.276] (==) RADEON(0): DRI3 disabled
[  1096.276] (==) RADEON(0): Backing store enabled
[  1096.276] (WW) RADEON(0): Direct rendering disabled
[  1096.276] (II) RADEON(0): Acceleration disabled
[  1096.276] (==) RADEON(0): DPMS enabled
[  1096.276] (==) RADEON(0): Silken mouse enabled
[  1096.276] (II) RADEON(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[  1096.277] (--) RandR disabled
[  1096.284] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[  1096.284] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[  1096.284] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[  1096.286] (II) IGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[  1096.287] (II) IGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[  1096.287] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
```

LIBGL_DEBUG:

```
$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxgears
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
```

glxinfo:

```
$ glxinfo  | grep -i version
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Version: 18.0.0
    Max core profile version: 3.3
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.0.0-rc5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.0-rc5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 18.0.0-rc5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00

$ glxinfo  | grep -i direct
direct rendering: Yes
GL_ARB_direct_state_access, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, 
GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts, 
GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind, GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect,
```

Any ideas how I could further debug this issue or fix it?

**Edit:**

Tried amdgpu, but it gives the same result:

```
[   234.839] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[   234.839] (II) AMDGPU(0): Front buffer pitch: 7680 bytes
[   234.839] (==) AMDGPU(0): DRI3 disabled
[   234.839] (==) AMDGPU(0): Backing store enabled
[   234.839] (WW) AMDGPU(0): Direct rendering disabled
[   234.839] (II) AMDGPU(0): 2D and 3D acceleration disabled
[   234.839] (==) AMDGPU(0): DPMS enabled
[   234.839] (==) AMDGPU(0): Silken mouse enabled
[   234.839] (II) AMDGPU(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
```

Answer (score 2):

Turned out that libegl-mesa0 wasn't installed, so:

```
apt-get install libegl-mesa0
```

fixes it.